# How to calculate $\int \sqrt{\frac{t^2+1}{t+1}}\frac1tdt$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the integral
$$\int \sqrt{\frac{t^2+1}{t+1}}\frac1tdt$$

I try to let $t=\tan \theta$. But it seems complex.

Is there an easier way to solve it?

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+sqrt%28%281%2Bx%5E%28-2%29%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%29&dataset=) uses several special functions, but it might simplify.

Comment: @J.G.. The monster simplify a lot (in particular the front term is "just" $(1+i)^{3/2}$ but we stay with the three elliptic integrals, for sure.

Comment: The integrand involves square root of a cubic so elliptic integrals will be needed.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. I was waiting for you !! Cheers :-)

Comment: When you think that the result is almost $\int_1^x \sim2 \sqrt x$